# EF Core map object to multiple databases

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am building an object in .NET Core that will be mapped to a database using EF Core. However one of the properties of this object will need to be mapped to a separate read only database.

What I mean is this:

```
public class Sample
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public string SampleValue { get; set; }
}

[Keyless]
public class Location
{
    [Column("LOCATION_ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("LOCATION_DESC")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `Location` object is pulled from a read only Oracle database using a predefined SQL query and retrieved using the FromSQL method, which is why I have the `[Keyless]` attribute:

```
_dbContext.Locations.FromSql<Location>(query)
```

The `Sample` will be stored in a SQL database and the location would be stored in that database with the `Location ID`, so when I retrieve a `Sample` object, EF Core will pick up the ID and get it from the Oracle database and create the correct `Location` property and map it

Comment: EF Core doesn't deal with *databases*. It maps objects to tables. If you can view the tables you want through the same connection you can probably map them by specifying the schema and table names in the mappings.

Comment: If you need a separate connection though, it makes no sense to use a single DbContext at all. You aren't using the same connection so you can't generate or execute SQL statements that work against both databases. A DbContext is not a model of the database, it's a multi-entity repository and unit-of-work. It's perfectly fine to have multiple DbContext classes in a project, especially when you need different behavior. A read-only database doesn't need change tracking for example because nothing is saved

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you won't be able to populate `_dbContext.Locations.FromSql<Location>(query)`, because you would need to connect to different database.

DbContext is not used for managing state of 2 databases. If your domain entity (Sample) created from 2 different data sources, I would recommend not relying on ORM Framework and build the entity yourself.

```
var dbSample = _dbContext1.DbSample.Get();
var dbLocation = _dbLocationContext.DbLocation.Get(dbSample.locationId);

return SampleBuilder.Build(dbSample, dbLocation);
```

Downside of this approach is that you will have to implement mappings from Domain Entity to Database representation.
But this approach is more straight forward and quite easy to implement and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

So following what @vshishkarov I have decided to do:

```
public class Sample
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public string SampleValue { get; set; }
}

[Keyless]
public class Location
{
    [Column("LOCATION_ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("LOCATION_DESC")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var dbSample = _dbContext1.DbSample.Get();
var dbLocation = _dbLocationContext.DbLocation.Get(dbSample.locationId);

dbSample.Location = dbLocation;
return dbSample;
```